# How come in Postman my post request works but not in the browser even though I'm doing the same?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

In Postman, I can successfully authenticate (I'm using Passport) using my endpoint.  I can then open up a new tab and use a different endpoint to post to my SQL database - the file name (which the user uploads), email, and user_id.

In the browser, I can successfully authenticate.  However, when I try to upload a file and send along the user's bearer token (to detect which user's uploading), I get a 500 error that says:

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in file.
```

I've tried to send the email and id  in my post request but I get the same error.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Backend controller code:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $id = $request->user()->id;
    $email = $request->user()->email;
    
    $data = [
        'file_path' => $filePath,
        'user_id' => $id,
        'email' => $email
    ];

    DB::table('my db.photos')->insert($data);
    echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
}
```

Frontend code:

```
fileUpload(file) {
    const formData = new FormData()

    console.log(this.state.access_token);

    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.set('access_token', "Bearer " + this.state.access_token);
    // formData.set('email', this.getEmail());
    // formData.set('user_id', this.getId());

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/myendpont/wall-of-fame', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => { console.error(error) });
}
```

Comment: Please add the error logs, it is important.

Comment: @rian I posted what I see in the logs in the backend

Comment: yup , `$id = $request->user()->id;` maybe the error com from here, can't get authenticated user from request. check your access_token in `fromdata` and `header`

Comment: @rian the weird part's that when I run `dd($id, $email);`, the correct information come up.  I'm not sure why it's not working in the browser.

Comment: Can you update your answer with error message from `laravel.log`? That should tell you on which line error occurred... Also, how did you setup the jwt token in laravel? Did you follow the laravel docs? [In the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#passing-the-access-token) it says to set the following `headers`: `Accept` and `Authorization`, but I don't see that in your JS logic...

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this?

```js
formData.append('access_token', "Bearer " + this.state.access_token);
```